# removing the image from the screen and the input file

Tags: jquery, html

I am loading several images with an input file, using jquery and html. How can I remove the screen image and input file information? using for example a click event on the image?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on("change", "#UploadIMG", function(e) {
    showThumbnail(this.files);
  });


  function showThumbnail(files) {
    var TotalArquivos = files.length;
    $('#DivImagens').html('');

    for (var i = 0; i < TotalArquivos; i++) {

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event) {
        //$($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo('#DivImagens').width(150);

        var EstruturaImg = '';
        EstruturaImg = '<div class="col-md-3">';
        EstruturaImg += '<img id="thumbnail' + i + '"';
        EstruturaImg += 'src = "' + event.target.result + '"';
        EstruturaImg += 'class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" alt="Imagem' + i + ' " width="150"/> ';
        EstruturaImg += '</div>';

        $('#DivImagens').append(EstruturaImg);

      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);

    }

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="DivImagens">

</div>

<input type="file" name="UploadIMG" multiple class="form-control" id="UploadIMG">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to reset an input of type file. You'll need to replace it.

Here's a fairly crude example... I'm sure you can get the same result with more elegant code.

```
$(document).on("change", "#UploadIMG", function(e) {
    showThumbnail(this.files);
    $(this).remove();
    $("#DivImagens").after('<input type="file" name="UploadIMG" multiple class="form-control" id="UploadIMG">');
  });
```

Comment: sorry but I could not quite understand what you meant

Comment: After your showThumbnail function has completed you need to remove the input and then re add it again.